# Django URL Case issue

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I'm using the following regex to build my urls as follows:

...templates/file

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.template_type, name="template"),
url(r'^(?P<template>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.template_file, name="file"),
```

The first line in here works fine pulling the slug field from the template model. It's the second line where I have the problem. In the second line

- the **slug** is pulled from a File Model field
- **template** is pulled from a Foreign Key field in the File Model of the Template Model

Although everything is working almost fine. The Foreign Key pulls the title rather than the slug from the Template Model making the url case insensitive.

eg
**website.com/template** - works fine but then goes to **website.com/Template/file** that also works, but if a user deleted the file from the url to try to go back to website.com/Template they would get a 404 error.

I hope that makes sense. I've tried making the urls case insensitive with (?i) but that has not worked.

Thanks

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? Is that not the expected behavior ? How do you intend to handle this ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\w` isn't case sensitive. I think it is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So your problem is likely somewhere else. Given what you have posted, it seems like *website.com/template* will get routed to the first URL where the slug value is *template*. Is that what you expected?

Comment: If I use the url localhost/template I get the page I want, but if I use localhost/Template I get a 404. I think the problem is how I'm pulling in that initial template part of the URL. It's pulling in the title from the Model rather than the slug, which on the website I want, but not in the URL